# How to setup PyCharm for Shell/Bash scripts

Tags: python, windows, bash, shell, pycharm

I've been struggling for a long time now to get this running but I just couldn't do it. I am runnning PyCharm Professional on Win10 and I want to code and run Shell scripts, but I cannot get it to work. There is this Shell Plugin from Pycharm but there is just not enough documention for me to understand how it has to be setup.
How do I have to setup PyCharm in order to Run/Debug Shell scripts?

I tried changing the shell used by the Terminal to the WSL Ubuntu shell, which actually worked. Thus I can now manually execute the bash script via the terminal.

I also tried changing the Run/Debug configuration.
[changed Run/Debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDVU1.png)

as suggesteed, changing the interpreter to bash.exe led to an error message. 
[interpreter changed to bash.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWivE.png)

I tried bash.exe, ubuntu.exe and cmd.exe as shells for terminal, all of which threw a file not found error. As before executing it manually with the wsl path format(/mnt/c/..) works. [manual execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGCVc.png)

["file not found"-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfnOZ.png)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: You cannot run shell scripts natively on Windows. You need a proper environment, such as WSL, Windows Subsystem for Linux. If the PyCharm version is >= 2018.3 EAP 7, WSL support is there - for Python configuration is quite simple, run "Add Python interpreter". You can also set the terminal to point to the WSL, go to Settings > Tools > Terminal > Application settings and put wsl.exe in the "shell path" field.

Comment: @KasiaGauza That's exactly what I want to do! :-) I just edited the question. Getting the Terminal to use WSL worked but getting the Run/Debug function to work is where my problem lies.

Comment: I think what I am looking for is a way to set the interpreter PC uses for shell scripts?!

Comment: I guess, in this case the interpreter should be _bash.exe_, rather than _ubuntu.exe_ (btw. please run test in PowerShell or cmd: `bash -c 'ls -l'`)

Comment: @KasiaGauza I did and it worked, listing all the directories.
Should I change the interpreter to bash.exe?

Comment: Please try changing it.

Comment: @KasiaGauza so using bash.exe as interpreter works, but now there is the problem that I get a file not found error(I edited the question with added pic). I guess that's because of the different versions of the file path provided by win10 and needed for shell.

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood something. I think with bash script you actually don't want to do debugging and trialruns the way you would with a python script. maybe I was looking for a solution to something that shouldnt be done in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess it was my misunderstanding in the end, that you can't really work with shell scripts like you do with python. meaning debugging etc and watching variables. I am trying to reduce my file shuffling code in bash anyways and try to stay mainly in python so there is now another motivation for that. thank you very much for helping me though.